# Showing aler diaog box in async task which is outside the activity (after execution is completed )

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

[image]

I want to show the alertdialogbox in the async task onpostExecute method which is a differnt class and not written as an inner class. I am currently passing the activity in the async task constructor and using its context in the alerdialog but the application is crashing. Kindly help how it can be achieved.

Attached is the error I am getting, From the error I thought the I will have to use the handler as i am updating the UI so I added handler and put the alerbox inside it. but this way the application doesnt crash but also doesnt show the aletbox. The handler should not be used as I have read that the onpostExecute is called in the UI thread. Kindly tell me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post stacktrace of error.

Comment: As pointed out by codeMagic, please share some code and please say when you want to display the dialog as that is not clear from your question. This link might help also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @Eenvincible I want to display the alerbox once the task excution is completed.

Comment: @GPW - Post code of `showAlert()` method.

Comment: Can you please copy the logcat and paste it into your post? It's so much easier for people who are trying to help you. But I'm guessing you are using `getApplicationContext()` instead of your `Activity Context`

Comment: @codeMagic I am using the Main activity context like this : AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(imageUploadMainActivity.getApplicationContext());

Comment: @codeMagic : Can you please tell me the correct way.

Comment: I've posted an answer but if that doesn't work then you need to post relevant code, as asked for above, or else it's really just a guessing game from there.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `Activity Context` instead of `Application Context`. You think this is what you are doing here

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(imageUploadMainActivity.getApplicationContext());
```

but you are still calling `getApplicationContext()` which , guess what, returns the `Application Context` ;)

Instead us

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(imageUploadMainActivity);
```

Assuming that `imageUploadMainActivity` is the variable which references the `Context` you passed to the `AsyncTask`. But, since you haven't shown that code, I can't say for sure.

Comment: I did exactly what you told, but i am still getting the same error. here is my code :  Main Activity :       new UploadFileToServer(getApplicationContext()).execute(filePath);                   Async task :  public UploadFileToServer(Context context) {
  super();
  MainActivityContext = context;
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

Comment: onpostexecute : AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivityContext); Kindly help

Comment: I think your `Context` might be null but it's hard to say. Code in comments is so difficult to read and follow